# Use package manager in a Cloud Foundry instance

Tags: cloud-foundry

Can I use `apt-get` or other package managers in Cloud Foundry buildpacks or `.profile` scripts that come with apps; and if I can, how to do it? I expect to do it the same way as in a dockerfile, but it doesn't work with or without `sudo` in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use apt-get or other package managers in Cloud Foundry buildpacks or .profile scripts that come with apps; and if I can, how to do it?

No.  Running `apt-get` or a package manager would typically require root access and you do not get root access when the build pack runs or when your application runs (this is a difference w/Docker).

That said, you can do anything that doesn't require root access, so if you found a package manager that installed in the vcap user's home directory and didn't need root then you could use that.

It depends on what you're trying to install, but in some cases you can work around this by downloading the .deb or .rpm file and manually extracting the binaries.  This typically works OK for things like shared libraries.  Just download the precompiled binary that matches your stack (`cflinuxfs2` == Ubuntu Trusty).  For other things, you can build your own binaries from source.  This is what the build pack's do, see [binary-builder](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/binary-builder).

Hope that helps!

Comment: So, for example, if I want to add an extension to php buildpack (like php-apc or pwgen), instead of installing it from apt-get, it will be fine to just copy the .so file to its correct directory?

Comment: To expand on Daniel's answer, you probably don't want non-deterministic operations happening inside a buildpack. For example when you `apt-get`, you might get a different version of a dependency depending on what the app is staged.

Comment: @QuanTranGia - Look at binary-builder, mentioned above.  That's how we build PHP & all of the extensions.  If you need an extension that's not supplied out of the box, submit an issue (or better yet a PR) and it's very likely to get added.